# get bounding rect of range slider within standard html5 audio element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find out the exact position in relation to the [desktop only] browser window of the playback cue point (the round button that moves as media plays back) and the client bounding rect via `getClientRects()` or `getClientBoundingRect()` of the whole range slider itself. Is this possible in pure javascript? The html5 component looks different on every browser of course, so it's position and dimension will be different where-ever I go.

[image]

Chrome's developer tools shows their browser using a shadow object to represent the elements. But I don't seem to be able to gather these elements using javascript.

[image]

It seems the best way is to find the bounding rect, say `document.querySelector("audio").getClientBoundingRect()` and then use a magic function and browser sniffing and the playback currentTime property and so on to come up with a highly fragile hack to represent the actual position in pixels of the dot... that's the approach I'm currently taking, but would like something better.

pps I'm looking for the way to do this with the standard html5 audio controls for the browser. I realise I can roll my own.

Comment: is there a specific reason you want to get the position of the progress tracker (which as you pointed out is entirely implementation-dependent) rather than simply looking at the data on which its position is based, namely `currentTime` and `duration`?

Answer (score 0):

See if this dirty code is util

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #div1 {
            width:600px;
        }
        #div2 {
            position:relative;
        }
        #div3 {
            position:absolute;
            border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
            left:101px;
            right:187px;
            top:-28px;
            height:14px;
            background:#fff;
        }
        audio {
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <audio controls id="player">
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
        <div id="div2">
            <div id="div3">
                <div style="position:relative;">
                    <div id="btn" style="position:absolute;border-radius:50%;background:red;width:10px;height:10px;top:2px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#player').on('timeupdate', function() {
        document.getElementById('btn').style.left = '' + (this.currentTime / this.duration * 100) + '%';
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no not at all, I want the *client bounding rect* of the button element. these are screen based coordinates (x,y,width,height) of the element. I want to position another element (a set of bezier curves drawn in a svg element) to have a reference to the exact on screen position of the playback head (plus other elements in standard browser specific audio controls).

Comment: Is it this?

    $('#player').offset().top;
    $('#player').offset().left;

Comment: that's the same as `document.querySelector("audio").getClientBoundingRect()` which is the rectangle box that the player sits in. I want the control surfaces within the player, if possible. the `audio > (shadow root) > div[psuedo='-webkit-media-controls'] > div[psuedo='-webkit-media-controls-enclosure'] > div[psuedo='-webkit-media-controls-panel'] > input[type='range'] -> (shadow root) -> div > div > #thumb` (but I can't see how to gather than object with javascript, or even css)

Comment: I think this is not possible and each browser is different. But you can build your own control. It is not better?

Comment: it is an alternative, yes. however solving the problem here would also solve a number of things I'm trying to achieve; it does not seem currently possible (but might become so as standards settle)

Comment: I understood. Tomorrow I will write a dirty solution for you get the progress round position